# My ConnectFour game works when it's a square grid but not in a rectangle grid

Tags: java

My connect four game program works when the `GRID_HEIGHT` and `GRID_WIDTH` is the same but my assignment requires the height to be 6 and the width to be 7. It doesn't work when I set it to 6 and 7 however for some reason it works when the width is 7 and the height is 6, though I need the opposite. For this version, the system instantly crashes when an input is entered, though it works perfectly on a square grid. Thanks for any help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WrittenStuff 
{
  public static final int GRID_HEIGHT=7;
  public static final int GRID_WIDTH=7;
  int totalMovesPlayed;
  char[][] board;

  public WrittenStuff()
  {
    board=new char[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];
    totalMovesPlayed=0;
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    WrittenStuff c4=new WrittenStuff();
    System.out.println("WELCOME TO CONNECT FOUR!!!");
    c4.printBoard();
    outer:
      while(true)
    {
      int column=0;
      //PLAYER 1.
      while(true)
      {
        System.out.print("\n\nPlayer 1 play:");
        column = input.nextInt();
        column = column-1;
        if(c4.isPlayable(column))
        {
          if(c4.playMove(column, 'X'))
          {
            c4.printBoard();
            System.out.println("\n\nPlayer 1 wins!!!");
            break outer;
          }
          break;
        }
        else{
          System.out.println("Column "+column+" is already full!!");
        }
      }
      c4.printBoard();

      //PLAYER 2.    
      while(true)
      {
        System.out.print("\n\nPlayer 2 play:");
        column = input.nextInt();
        column = column-1;
        if(c4.isPlayable(column))
        {
          if(c4.playMove(column, 'O'))
          {
            c4.printBoard();
            System.out.println("\n\nPlayer 2 wins!!!");
            break outer;
          }
          break;
        }
        else{
          System.out.println("Column "+column+" is already full!!");
        }
      }
      c4.printBoard();

      if(c4.isFull())
      {
        System.out.print("Game drawn. Both of you suck at this!!! ");
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  public void printBoard()
  {
    for(int vert=0;vert<board.length;vert++)
    {
      for(int hori=0;hori<board[0].length;hori++)
      {
        if(board[vert][hori] == 0)
        {
          System.out.print("|" + "_" + "|");
        }
        else
        {


        System.out.print("|" + board[vert][hori] + "|");
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    for(int vert=0;vert<GRID_WIDTH;vert++)
      System.out.print(" "+(vert+1)+" ");
    System.out.println();
  }

  public boolean playMove(int column, char playerNum)
  {
    int vert=0;
    for(vert=0;vert<GRID_HEIGHT;vert++)
    {
      if(board[vert][column] == 'X' || board[vert][column] == 'O')
      {
        board[vert-1][column]=playerNum;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(vert == GRID_HEIGHT)
    {
      board[vert-1][column]=playerNum;
    }

    totalMovesPlayed++;
    return isConnected(vert-1,column);
  }

  public boolean isPlayable(int column)
  {
    return board[0][column] == 0; 
  }

  public boolean isFull()
  {
    return totalMovesPlayed == GRID_HEIGHT*GRID_WIDTH;
  }

  public boolean isConnected(int x, int y)
  {
    int num=board[x][y];
    int count=0;
    int vert=y;

    //HORIZONTAL.
    while(vert<GRID_WIDTH && board[x][vert] == num)
    {
      count++; vert++;
    }
    vert=y-1;
    while(vert>=0 && board[x][vert] == num)
    {
      count++; vert--;
    }
    if(count == 4){
      return true;}

    //VERTICAL.
    count=0; int hori=x;
    while(hori<GRID_HEIGHT && board[hori][y] == num)
    {
      count++; hori++;
    }
    if(count == 4){
      return true;}

    //SECONDARY DIAGONAL.
    count=0; vert=x; hori=y;
    while(vert<GRID_WIDTH && hori<GRID_HEIGHT && board[vert][hori] == num)
    {
      count++; vert++; hori++;
    }
    vert=x-1; hori=y-1;
    while(vert>=0 && hori>=0 && board[vert][hori] == num)
    {
      count++; vert--; hori--;
    }
    if(count == 4){
      return true;}

    //LEADING DIAGONAL.
    count=0; vert=x; hori=y;
    while(vert<GRID_WIDTH && hori>=0 && board[vert][hori] == num)
    {
      count++; vert++; hori--;
    }
    vert=x-1; hori=y+1;
    while(vert>=0 && hori<GRID_HEIGHT && board[vert][hori] == num)
    {
      count++; vert--; hori++;
    }
    if(count == 4){
      return true;}

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instantly crashes? Surely, some exception is thrown. Do you think that when you ask for help, providing the exact text of the exception might help?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at all your uses of `board`, I find:

```
board[vert][hori]
board[vert][hori]
board[vert][column]
board[vert][column]
board[vert-1][column]
board[vert-1][column]
board[0][column]
board[x][y]
board[x][vert]
board[x][vert]
board[hori][y]
board[vert][hori]
board[vert][hori]
board[vert][hori]
board[vert][hori]
```

So, if first dimension is indexed by `vert`, and second dimension is indexed by `hori`, why is second dimension variable sometimes named `column`, not `hori`? Consistent naming is important for the human understanding of your code, including your own, to prevent coding errors.

But more importantly, what's up with the `[x][y]`, `[x][vert]`, and `[hori][y]`? Assuming `y` is equivalent to `vert`, and that `x` is equivalent to `hori` (again, *consistent naming*, please), aren't those **reversed**?